# Is opening several resources in one try-statement unreliable? Why?

Tags: java, try-with-resources

This program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    static Set<String> openResources = new TreeSet<>();

    static class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {

        boolean close;
        MyResource encapsulatedResource;
        String name;

        MyResource(String id, boolean exceptionOnCreate, boolean exceptionOnClose, MyResource encapsulatedResource) {
            this.close = exceptionOnClose;
            this.encapsulatedResource = encapsulatedResource;
            this.name = id;
            if (exceptionOnCreate) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception when creating " + id);
            }
            openResources.add(id);
            System.out.println(name + " is now open");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            if (close) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception when closing " + name);
            }
            if (encapsulatedResource != null) {
                encapsulatedResource.close();
            }
            openResources.remove(name);
            System.out.println(name + " was successfully closed");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (AutoCloseable resource1 = new MyResource("resource1", false, false, null);
                MyResource resource2 = new MyResource("resource2", false, true, null);
                AutoCloseable resource3 = new MyResource("resource3", false, false, resource2);
                AutoCloseable resource4 = new MyResource("resource4", true, false, null);) {
            System.out.println("main program");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("openResources: " + openResources);
    }
}
```

Has following output:

```
resource1 is now open
resource2 is now open
resource3 is now open
resource1 was successfully closed
Exception when creating resource4
openResources: [resource2, resource3]
```

I expected that when using try-with-resources all resources are properly closed, and I will not have any leaked. However, here, resources 2 and 3 are leaked. Why? Can’t I rely on that syntax?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the "reliability" of try-catch and everything to do with the way you've connected your resources and the fact that they throw exceptions. Closing resource3 will throw an exception when attempting to close the encapsulated resource2. Closing resource2 will throw an exception.

Comment: Yes indeed the example you have created in a bit flawed as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Resources 2 and 3 are "leaked" because of the way that your exceptions are defined. Since resource 4 throws an exception on create, the created resources will be closed. Resource 3 will attempt to close, but because it is actually trying to close resource 2, resource 3 will throw an exception (note: this exception is suppressed because it is thrown while servicing the original exception in the try section). Closing resource 2 will also result in a suppressed exception, leaving resource 1 with the only closed resource.

Answer (score -1):

As per [JAVA docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1):

> If one automatic closing of an initialized resource completes abruptly
> because of a throw of value V, and all other automatic closings of
> initialized resources complete normally, then the try-with-resources
> statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V.

So, this is working as design. The reason for introducing try with resources was to reduce developers task and handle resource handling by itself. In terms of reliability, even the old way of code would have lead to the same resource leak. Let's try to translate our code with the way mentioned in JAVA docs below:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1

[image]

Let's try to understand this by re-modifying your code and writing it in old way of creating resources in try and closing in finally

```
public class Main {

    static Set<String> openResources = new TreeSet<>();

    static class MyResource implements AutoCloseable {

        boolean close;
        MyResource encapsulatedResource;
        String name;

        MyResource(String id, boolean exceptionOnCreate, boolean exceptionOnClose, MyResource encapsulatedResource) {
            this.close = exceptionOnClose;
            this.encapsulatedResource = encapsulatedResource;
            this.name = id;
            if (exceptionOnCreate) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception when creating " + id);
            }
            openResources.add(id);
            System.out.println(name + " is now open");
        }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            if (close) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Exception when closing " + name);
            }
            if (encapsulatedResource != null) {
                encapsulatedResource.close();
            }
            openResources.remove(name);
            System.out.println(name + " was successfully closed");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AutoCloseable resource1 = null, resource3 = null, resource4 = null;
        MyResource resource2 = null;
        try {
            resource1 = new MyResource("resource1", false, false, null);
            resource2 = new MyResource("resource2", false, true, null);
            resource3 = new MyResource("resource3", false, false, resource2);
            resource4 = new MyResource("resource4", true, false, null);
            System.out.println("main program");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                resource1.close();
                resource2.close();
                resource3.close();
                resource4.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("openResources: " + openResources);
    }
}
```

If you will run this program, you will get below output:

```
resource1 is now open
resource2 is now open
resource3 is now open
Exception when creating resource4
resource1 was successfully closed
Exception when closing resource2
openResources: [resource2, resource3]
```

> As you can see resource 2 and resource3 are the leaked resources as
> closure of resource 2 lead to exception which furhter block closure of
> resource 3.

Similary, with try with resources, it expect no exception is thrown at time of closure and if thrown, closure of resources will be terminated at that point of time.

> This does not mean that try with resources are unreliable or older
> resource handling was any better. It just mean that the closable
> resource is not working correctly and should have closed or at least
> should have handled exception so that remaining resource closure can
> continue.

Comment: You've posted the translation, but your code is not equivalent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks for your comment. I have posted what JAVA docs say, but if you feel its different, please share the equivalent for the above code.

Comment: Among other things, you've not implemented this correctly _If the ResourceSpecification declares n > 1 resources, then ResourceSpecification_tail consists of the 2nd, 3rd, ..., n'th resources declared in ResourceSpecification, in the same order (and the try-catch-finally statement is itself a try-with-resources statement)._ Each `close()` call is wrapped in a `null` check and its own `try-catch` statement. It calls `close` on all resources. In your code, it'll stop after the first call that fails.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As per JAVA docs: _If one automatic closing of an initialized resource completes abruptly because of a throw of value V, and all other automatic closings of initialized resources complete normally, then the try-with-resources statement completes abruptly because of a throw of the value V._ Which leads to the case that all the close are in one try catch only

Comment: No it doesn't. It specifically says _[...] and all other automatic closings [...]_. Your code doesn't perform all the _other closings_ if, for example, the first one fails. What that quote says is that if only one of many fail, then the corresponding exception is the one that is thrown from the try-with-resources statement. If more than one throws an exception, then there's the whole suppressed exception behavior applied.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes agreed, so here I show cased an example with one exception only and not with multiple exception. How do you suggest to showcase this example ?

Comment: With 4 resources, it's going to nest pretty far, it's not worth the trouble. I think I would just show 2 resources being closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174665/discussion-between-aman-chhabra-and-sotirios-delimanolis).